# what profile / resolution should the video be in? so that Android's Emulator 3.0 can play HLS streams

Tags: android, http-live-streaming

I have my Android Emulator running Android 3.0, on which when I test Apple's sample HLS link: "http://devimages.apple.com/iphone/samples/bipbop/gear1/prog_index.m3u8" it runs successfully.

I have created one custom file "maqm.m3u8" by reading Apple's specification for HLS
Ref: (https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/StreamingMediaGuide/Introduction/Introduction.html)

But used free encoding (using ffmpegx) and segmenting (open source segmenter) methods to create my custom .m3u8 file.

When I test this .m3u8 file by uploading it on the server (www.simsanraj.comlu.com/maqm.m3u8) it played successfully on safari 5.0.3 and on iPad2.

However, the same stream when I test on my Android emulator (using the same code which played bipbop sample file successfully), Emulator crashes.

Following logs get generated:

`I/StagefrightPlayer(  33): setDataSource('httplive://www.simsanraj.comlu.com/maqm.m3u8')`

`I/LiveSession(  33): onConnect 'http://www.simsanraj.comlu.com/maqm.m3u8'`

`I/NuHTTPDataSource(   33): connect to www.simsanraj.comlu.com:80/maqm.m3u8 @0`

`I/NuHTTPDataSource(   33): connect to www.simsanraj.comlu.com:80/maqm.m3u8 @0`

`I/NuHTTPDataSource(   33): connect to simsanraj.comlu.com:80/maq.ts @0`

`W/ActivityManager(   74): Launch timeout has expired, giving up wake lock!`

`W/ActivityManager(   74): Activity idle timeout for ActivityRecord{41aafa80 com.example.testhls/.MediaPlayerDemo_Video}`

`I/ESQueue (   33): found something resembling an AAC syncword at offset 36`

`F/ESQueue (   33): frameworks/base/media/libstagefright/mpeg2ts/ESQueue.cpp:223 CHECK_NE( channel_configuration,0u) failed: 0 vs. 0`

`I/DEBUG   (   31): *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** **`

`I/DEBUG   (   31): Build fingerprint: 'generic/sdk/generic:3.0/HONEYCOMB/104254:eng/test-keys'`
I/DEBUG   (   31): pid: 33, tid: 388  >>> /system/bin/mediaserver <<<
I/DEBUG   (   31): signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 1 (SEGV_MAPERR), fault addr deadbaad
I/DEBUG   (   31):  r0 deadbaad  r1 0000000c  r2 00000027  r3 00000000
I/DEBUG   (   31):  r4 00000080  r5 aff46658  r6 4070f948  r7 00000000
I/DEBUG   (   31):  r8 a2b72589  r9 00012edc  10 00100000  fp 00000001
I/DEBUG   (   31):  ip ffffffff  sp 4070f488  lr aff193e9  pc aff15f58  cpsr 00000030
I/DEBUG   (   31):          #00  pc 00015f58  /system/lib/libc.so`

`I/DEBUG   (   31):          #01  pc 00001466  /system/lib/liblog.so (__android_log_assert)`

`I/NuHTTPDataSource(   33): connect to www.simsanraj.comlu.com:80/maqm.m3u8 @0`

`W/AudioSystem(   74): AudioPolicyService server died!`

`W/AudioSystem(  380): AudioFlinger server died!`

`W/IMediaDeathNotifier(  380): media server died`

`E/MediaPlayer(  380): error (100, 0)`

`W/AudioSystem(  140): AudioFlinger server died!`

`W/AudioSystem(  140): AudioPolicyService server died!`

`I/ServiceManager(   28): service 'media.audio_flinger' died`

`I/ServiceManager(   28): service 'media.player' died`

`I/ServiceManager(   28): service 'media.camera' died`

`I/ServiceManager(   28): service 'media.audio_policy' died`

`E/MediaPlayerDemo(  380): error: Prepare failed.: status=0x64`

`E/MediaPlayerDemo(  380): java.io.IOException: Prepare failed.: status=0x64`

`E/MediaPlayerDemo(  380):  at android.media.MediaPlayer.prepare(Native Method)`

`E/MediaPlayerDemo(  380):  at com.example.testhls.MediaPlayerDemo_Video.playVideo(MediaPlayerDemo_Video.java:84)`

`E/MediaPlayerDemo(  380):  at com.example.testhls.MediaPlayerDemo_Video.surfaceCreated(MediaPlayerDemo_Video.java:138)`

`E/MediaPlayerDemo(  380):  at android.view.SurfaceView.updateWindow(SurfaceView.java:565)`

`E/MediaPlayerDemo(  380):  at android.view.SurfaceView.access$000(SurfaceView.java:84)`

`E/MediaPlayerDemo(  380):  at
android.view.SurfaceView$3.onPreDraw(SurfaceView.java:173)`

`E/MediaPlayerDemo(  380):  at android.view.ViewTreeObserver.dispatchOnPreDraw(ViewTreeObserver.java:590)`

`E/MediaPlayerDemo(  380):  at android.view.ViewRoot.performTraversals(ViewRoot.java:1325)`

`E/MediaPlayerDemo(  380):  at android.view.ViewRoot.handleMessage(ViewRoot.java:1944)`

`E/MediaPlayerDemo(  380):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)`

`E/MediaPlayerDemo(  380):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:126)`

`E/MediaPlayerDemo(  380):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3997)`

`E/MediaPlayerDemo(  380):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)`

`E/MediaPlayerDemo(  380):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:491)`

`E/MediaPlayerDemo(  380):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:841)`

`E/MediaPlayerDemo(  380):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:599)`

`E/MediaPlayerDemo(  380):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)`

`D/MediaPlayerDemo(  380): surfaceChanged called`

`I/BootReceiver(   74): Copying /data/tombstones/tombstone_05 to DropBox (SYSTEM_TOMBSTONE)`

`I/ActivityManager(   74): Displayed com.example.testhls/.MediaPlayerDemo_Video: +15s400ms`

`D/dalvikvm(  380): GC_CONCURRENT freed 123K, 4% free 6510K/6727K, paused 4ms+26ms`

`I/        (  391): ServiceManager: 0xf798`

`D/AudioHardwareInterface(  391): setMode(NORMAL)`

`I/CameraService(  391): CameraService started (pid=391)`

`I/AudioFlinger(  391): AudioFlinger's thread 0xff88 ready to run`

`D/dalvikvm(  147): GC_EXPLICIT freed <1K, 18% free 14315K/17287K, paused 4ms+4ms`

`D/dalvikvm(  303): GC_EXPLICIT freed 196K, 5% free 6280K/6599K, paused 10ms+3ms`

Also when I checked this stream on native device (Android's tablet - it runs Honeycomb 3.2.1), the tablet hangs.

From my readings, I have learnt something called baseline profile that needs to be configured to play HTTP live streams on Android but not really sure how to configure it.

Please give some hints on where exactly should I start my investigation.